# Can I query a aggregated query and a specific row's query when using subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and I wanted to return the results of a specific value and the average of similar values. I have gotten the average part working but I'm not sure how to do the specific value part.

For more context, I have a list of carbon emissions by companies. I wanted the average of a industry based on a company's industry(working perfectly below), but I am not sure how to add the specific companies info.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    year, AVG(carbon) AS AVG_carbon,
    --    carbon as CompanyCarbon, <--my not working attempt
FROM
    "company"."carbon" c 
WHERE
    LOWER(c.ticker) IN (SELECT LOWER(g4.ticker)
                        FROM "company"."General" g4
                        WHERE industry = (SELECT industry 
                                          FROM "company"."General" g3 
                                          WHERE LOWER(g3.ticker) = 'ibm.us')) 
GROUP BY 
    c.year
ORDER BY 
    year ASC;
```

The current result is:

```
year    avg_carbon
--------------------------------
1998    7909.0000000000000000
1999    19465.500000000000
2000    19478.000000000000
2001    182679.274509803922
2002    179821.156862745098
```

My desired output is:

```
year    avg_carbon.             Carbon
---------------------------------------
1998    7909.0000000000000000   343
1999    19465.500000000000      544
2000    19478.000000000000      653
2001    182679.274509803922     654
2002    179821.156862745098     644
```

(adding the carbon column based on "IBM" carbon

Here's my Carbon table:

```
ticker  year    carbon
-----------------------
hurn.us 2016    6282
hurn.us 2015    6549
hurn.us 2014    5897
hurn.us 2013    5300
hurn.us 2012    5340
ibm.us  2019    1496520
ibm.us  2018    1438365
```

Based on my limited knowledge, I think my where the statement is causing the problem. Right now I took at a company, get a list of tickers/identifiers of the same industry then create an average for each year.

I tried to just call the carbon column but I think because it's processing the list of tickers, it's not outputting the result I want.

What can I do? Also if I'm making any other mistakes you see above please let me know.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite hepful.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I had it added but it's in the middle. I'll update so it's marked as desired output

Comment: In first row of your result carbon is 343.  And in second column it's 544. Please explain the logic behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data nd output do not match. So I can't say for sure but this might be the answer you are looking for.

```
select year, AVG(carbon) AS AVG_carbon,
max(case when lower(ticker)  = 'ibm.us' then carbon else 0 end) as CompanyCarbon
from "company"."carbon" c 
GROUP BY c.year
order by year ASC;
```

This will select max(carbon) for any year as CompanyCarbon if lower(ticker)  = 'ibm.us'. Average will be calculated as you did.

To select only rows having positive value in CompanyCarbon column:

```
select year, AVG_carbon, CompanyCarbon
from 
(
    select year, AVG(carbon) AS AVG_carbon,
    max(case when lower(ticker)  = 'ibm.us' then carbon else 0 end) as   CompanyCarbon
    from "company"."carbon" c 
    GROUP BY c.year
    order by year ASC;
)t where carbon > 0
```

Comment: thank you, it worked! I didn't think of the sub query in the select statement. Thank you

Comment: weird question, is there a way to make it so CompanyCarbon is not null?

Comment: I have added else part to produce 0 instead of null.

Comment: You are most welcome @Lostsoul. Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks, I meant like not display that row at all then..not fill it with 0.

Comment: I tried this but no luck - (after the where statement) and  carbon != '0'

Comment: Do you want to avoid rows where carbon is not available? Then I have revised my answer. You can use an outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer that Kazi provided you can use the `FILTER` syntax on an aggregate which makes it a bit more readable than the `case/when` IMO.

```sql
SELECT 
   year, 
   AVG(carbon) as avg_carbon, 
   MAX(carbon) FILTER (WHERE ticker = 'ibm.us') as company_carbon 
FROM company_carbon 
GROUP BY year 
ORDER by year;
```